# Inserting string into specific part of a javascript file

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7

I need to change one specific section of a javascript file by inserting a string, with python. Here is a small sample of the javascript file.

```
//----------------------------------------Peter Lighting Priorities-----------------------------------------------------
/*

// Lighting low prios for everything else//
peter_RenderBoy_lighting_lowPrios = {
    "fromProductionGroups" : ["peter_RenderBoy_lighting"],
    "matchFilters" : [
        {"user": "", "name": ""}     

    ],
    "toProductionGroup" : "",
    "priority" : 3

};

moveAndPrioritise(peter_RenderBoy_lighting_lowPrios);

// lighting normal and Approved LFL shots (emailed at 8pm) //
peter_RenderBoy_lighting_normalPrios = {
    "fromProductionGroups" : ["peter_RenderBoy_lighting"],
    "matchFilters" : [
        {"user": "", "name": ""}     

    ],
    "toProductionGroup" : "",
    "priority" : 2

};

moveAndPrioritise(peter_RenderBoy_lighting_normalPrios);
```

Here is the same sample of javascript showing the string "***INSERT_STRING_HERE***" in bold where it needs to be inserted:

```
//----------------------------------------Peter Lighting Priorities-----------------------------------------------------
/*

// Lighting low prios for everything else//
peter_RenderBoy_lighting_lowPrios = {
    "fromProductionGroups" : ["peter_RenderBoy_lighting"],
    "matchFilters" : [
        {"user": "", "name": ""}     

    ],
    "toProductionGroup" : "",
    "priority" : 3

};

moveAndPrioritise(peter_RenderBoy_lighting_lowPrios);

// lighting normal and Approved LFL shots (emailed at 8pm) //
peter_RenderBoy_lighting_normalPrios = {
    "fromProductionGroups" : ["peter_RenderBoy_lighting"],
    "matchFilters" : [
        {"user": "", "name": "***INSERT_STRING_HERE***"}     

    ],
    "toProductionGroup" : "",
    "priority" : 2

};

moveAndPrioritise(peter_RenderBoy_lighting_normalPrios);
```

This was my attempt so far, which merely shows that I've imported regex, but since gave up on my efforts with that, and am trying to loop through the  javascript file, but don't know how to proceed to achieve what I need:

```
import re
javascript_file = open('/depts/wranglers/frankie/farmtools/priorities/autoHook.js')
for line in javascript_file:
    if '// lighting normal and Approved LFL shots (emailed at 8pm) //' in line:
```

Comment: How is the Python script supposed to know which line it should insert the string into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see that comment line, set a variable. Then when you see the line with the pattern you want to replace, check whether the variable is set, and do the replacement.

```
with open('/depts/wranglers/frankie/farmtools/priorities/autoHook.js') as javascript_file, \
     open('/depts/wranglers/frankie/farmtools/priorities/autoHook.new.js') as new_file
    section_found = False
    for line in javascript_file:
        if '// lighting normal and Approved LFL shots (emailed at 8pm) //' in line:
            section_found = True
        elif '{"user": "", "name": ""}' and section_found:
            line = line.replace('"name": ""', '"name": "INSERT_STRING_HERE"')
            section_found = False
        new_file.write(line + "\n")
```